# Pipenv installing a local package but getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named"

Tags: python, pipenv, pipenv-install

I have a local project which I am developing and I want to install it into my pipenv so that I can try running some scripts that use the code I have developed.

I created a very basic setup.py located in the root of the project (`mypackage/setup.py`):

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

And have also added `__init__.py` files (although they are all empty, but that should be fine) into all of the desired directories within the project.

Then when I run `pipenv install /Users/me/path/to/mypackage` it tells me that it is installing 'mypackage', and then it even adds it to the pipfile.

But then when I run the venv `pipenv shell` and try importing the package `python -c 'import mypackage'` (also tried using python3 but same result), I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`.

I also tried to remove the venv `pipenv --rm` and re-install it `pipenv install`, but the same result. So at this point I'm a bit stuck on what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try to see where your virtual environment is and list of packages inside it.

```
pipenv --where
pipenv --venv
pipenv graph
```

Comment: Hmm, when I look it shows that mypackage is available in the venv. Looking at `pipenv graph`. Also the `--where` shows it is in the root of mypackage.

Comment: cant know whats issue without looking and debugging, look at poetry once its similar to pipenv. [link](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry)